# Push to an array in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I' m trying to get all the doctor users with  a specific id, but it does not work. Want the code does:
1. idDoctors contain all the ids from doctors from a specific hospital
2. specialities contain all the specialities form a spesific hospital
doctors should  be an array that retrieves firstname lastname and speciality of a doctor, but it doesn't

```
route.get('/doctor/:idHospital', authenticate,  async (req,res) => {
try{
    let idDoctors = await specialityService.getDoctorsId(req.params.idHospital);
    let specialities = await specialityService.allForHospital(req.params.idHospital)
    let doctors =  getDoctor(idDoctors, specialities)
    console.log(doctors)
    res.send(doctors)
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.sendStatus(500)
}
```

})

I tried this but i dont know how to return the doctors array in the previous function without..

```
function getDoctor(idDoctors, specialities) {
var doctors = new Array()
let doctor
    let i = 0;
    idDoctors.forEach(async(element) => {
        return userService.oneById(element.idDoctor).then((doc) => {
            doctor = {idDoctor: doc.id, lastName: doc.lastName, firstName: doc.firstName, speciality: specialities[i].speciality }
            doctors.push(doctor)
            i++;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    });
```

}

also tried this, but again Idk how to return the doctors array.. And i know that it return empty because that is executed before the promise. I am new to promises and didn't really  find an answer.

```
function getDoctor(idDoctors, specialities) {
var doctors = new Array()
let doc, doctor
    let i = 0;
    idDoctors.forEach(async(element) => {
        try{
            doc = await userService.oneById(element.idDoctor)
            doctor = {idDoctor: doc.id, lastName: doc.lastName, firstName: doc.firstName, speciality: specialities[i].speciality }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        doctors.push(doctor)
        i++;
    });
return doctors
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) here:

```js
async function getDoctor(idDoctors, specialities) {
  const promises = [];
  idDoctors.forEach((el) => {
    promises.push(userService.oneById(el.idDoctor))
  });
  const doctors = await Promise.all(promises)
  const result = doctors.map((doc, i) => ({
    idDoctor: doc.id,
    lastName: doc.lastName,
    firstName: doc.firstName,
    speciality: specialities[i].speciality
  }))

  return result;
}
```